# Looking for a specific text in .txt file

Tags: python

I am new at Python and for a simple project I tried to make a simple program using .txt file.

A sample text file looks like this:

```
Name = Garry
Age = 20
```

Then, I wrote this

```
Search = input("Whose age do you want to know? ")

    f = open("text exe.txt", "r")
    reviews = f.readlines()
    this_line = reviews[0].split(" = ")
    if this_line[1] == Search:
        print("yes")
    f.close()
```

When I tried to input "Garry" into Search, "yes" doesn`t come out. Does anyone know the reason? Thank you

Comment: Please post your sample data as code-formatted text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Understood. I thought by sending the screenshot, you could get a much clearer look of how the file looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome! Comparing strings can be very tricky: `this_line[1]` contains not only "Garry", but also e line separator "\r\n".

Although "Garry" (your input) and "Garry\r\n" (from your file) appear the same to us, they are considered different by `==` operator.

The solution below removes spaces and other non-visible characters around the word, producing the desired output:

```
Search = input("Whose age do you want to know? ")

f = open("text exe.txt", "r")
reviews = f.readlines()
this_line = reviews[0].split(" = ")
if this_line[1].strip() == Search.strip():
    print("yes")
f.close()
```

Comment: The line separator is just `\n` on most sane platforms, though the screen shot looks like the OP is on Windows.

Comment: I see.I also thought of the same thing (Garry in .txt file was not only "Garry"), I tried to fix it but still the error persisted. I didn't know you can erase the whatever-is-behind-Garry with strip. So, thank you for your help.

Comment: Happy new year! I'm glad I could help. If it solved your problem, please, select this answer as correct, to help others with similar problems

Answer (score 0):

This could solve your problem.

```
Search = input("Whose age do you want to know? ")
f = open("test.txt", "r")
reviews = f.readlines()
reviews = [x.strip() for x in reviews] 
# print(reviews)
this_line = reviews[0].split(" = ")
if this_line[1] == Search:
    print("yes")
    f.close()
```

Comment: Why would you strip all the lines if you are only processing the first?

Answer (score 0):

In the txt file the lines are separated with a `\n`. If you print `this_line` it will be `['Name = Gary\n', 'Age = 20\n']`. So you should replace the "\n" with a empty sting.
`if this_line[1].replace("\n","") == Search:` will work.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Why deal with lists , splits and loops when you can do it this way? You'll deal with that plenty when learning python, in the meantime, here's a nice clean solution:

```
search = input('Enter:')
f = open("text exe.txt", "r")
if search in f.read():
    print('Yes')
else:
    print('No')
f.close()
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
_INPUT_FILE = 'input.txt'

_OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.txt'

def main(): 

pattern = re.compile('^(.*)' +re.escape(sys.argv[1]) + '(.*)$') 

o = open(_OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') 

with open(_INPUT_FILE) as f: 

for line in f: 

match = pattern.match(line) 

if match is not None: 

o.write(match.group(1) + match.group(2) + os.linesep)

o.close() 

if __name__ == '__main__': 

main()
```